# JPA second level cache update in case of USE store mode

Tags: jpa, caching

I'm just reading about cache store modes in JPA, and I see the followings:

> If data is already in the cache, setting the store mode to USE will not force a refresh when data is read from the database.

It is really strange for me, because I don't understand that why is it great to not to update the cache if the database contains different state of the entity, and I am also curious about in which cases will the cache be updated and in which not.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Could you point me to the source of this quote?

Comment: @VikGamov The source of this quote is the following: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html